# Trouble Getting System.Drawing.Graphics to work in Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a C# Windows form in Visual Studio so I can draw on the form (like a basic version of Microsoft Paint).  I am working through an example in a C# 2012 book.  I have written the code verbatim, but when I build and run the program, I cannot actually draw anything on the form.  The code compiles successfully without any errors.  Can anyone see where the code can be improved so that I can successfully draw on the form?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace paint3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool shouldPaint = false;

    public Form1()  // constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shouldPaint = true;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shouldPaint = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldPaint)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.BlueViolet), e.X, e.Y, 4, 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

As far as Form1 is concerned, it's simply a blank form that is created when I click "New Windows Forms Application" in Visual Studio 2012.  I haven't added any buttons, text boxes, or other controls to Form1.

Comment: You need to put it in the Paint event

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldPaint)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            {
                graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.BlueViolet), e.X, e.Y, 4, 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

> I am trying to make a C# Windows form in Visual Studio so I can draw on the form (like a
>   basic version of Microsoft Paint). I am working through an example in
>   a C# 2012 book.

Alex Fr provided an excellent set of drawing tools in his [DrawTools article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools) and these tools serve as a basis for [Draw Tool Redux](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17893/Extensions-to-DrawTools).

Here's a tool I recently wrote by adding to Draw Tool Redux, it creates Epilogs for Mathematica:

[image]

The EyeDropper Colour Picker I got from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36540/Adobe-Eyedropper-Control

The Transparent Textbox I got from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo

Comment: Does `Form1_Paint` solve the OP's problem?  What's all this other stuff?

Comment: I think they're called pearls around here, but more specifically they are the instructions to build a better program than Microsoft Paint. Looking at the code *from the book*, I thought OP could do with info on a C# implementation of the MFC sample DRAWCLI. Sharing your research helps everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the paint events for drawing. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) will help you.
The link is just an example. you need to implement as per the requirements