# How can I draw a horizontal separator line with a title?

Tags: winforms, controls

I need to visually separate various areas on my form, and the `GroupBox` control is a bit 'heavy' for my desired look. I also need to label each separator with a title.

I've found various methods to partially do this, most popularly using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296161/722393) with the `Label` control:

1. Add a Label control to your form
2. Set Label Text to empty
3. Set BorderStyle to Fixed3D
4. Set AutoSize to false
5. Set Height to 2

However, techniques like this don't let us specify any text to use as a separator title.

How can I create a separator control that also displays the value of its `Text` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to accomplish this with a custom control. It looks like this at both design time and run time:

[image: Separator Control]

Here's the code:

```
Partial Public Class Line
  Inherits Control

  Private Sub Line_Paint(Sender As Line, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim oBackground As Rectangle
    Dim oTextSize As Size

    Dim _
      iX,
      iY As Integer

    oTextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Me.Text, Me.Font)

    Me.Height = oTextSize.Height + 3
    iX = 1
    iY = Me.Height / 2

    Using oPen As New Pen(Me.LineColor)
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(oPen, iX, iY, Me.Width - iX - 1, iY)
    End Using

    Using oPen As New Pen(Color.White)
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(oPen, iX + 1, iY + 1, Me.Width - iX, iY + 1)
    End Using

    If oTextSize.Height > 0 Then
      Using oBrush As New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)
        oBackground = New Rectangle(7, 1, oTextSize.Width - 2, oTextSize.Height)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, oBackground)
      End Using

      Using oBrush As New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, oBrush, 7, 1)
      End Using
    End If
  End Sub



  <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveBorder")>
  <Description("The color of the line.")>
  <Browsable(True)>
  <Category("Appearance")>
  Public Property LineColor As Color
    Get
      Return Me._LineColor
    End Get
    Set(Value As Color)
      Me._LineColor = Value
      Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
  End Property
  Private Property _LineColor As Color = SystemColors.ActiveBorder
End Class
```

Comment: There's also drawing tool controls in Winforms (similar to the one's in the VB6 days). I recall you have to install some PowerPack, this was 5 yrs ago and you're probably better off using the Graphics object thesedays.

Comment: **@JeremyThompson** Yes, thanks, I looked at that as well... but unfortunately the `Line` control doesn't have a `Text` property that can be used. ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488281(v=vs.120)))

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your solution, it's good. Just an FYI I've had great success with [Draw Tool Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17182111/495455).